# Finding ALL Non Repeating characters in a given string

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I was given the question:

Find ALL of the non-repeating characters in a given string;

After doing some Google searching it was clear to me that finding the first non repeating character was pretty common. I found many examples of how to do that, but I have not really found anything on how to find ALL of the non repeating characters instead of just the first one.

my example code so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

char findAllNonRepeating(const string& s) {

    unordered_map<char, int> m;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char c = tolower(s[i]);

        if (m.find(c) == m.end())
            m[c] = 1;
        else
            ++m[c];
    }

    auto best = m.begin();

    for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
        if (it->second <= best->second)
            best = it;

    return (best->first);
}


int main()
{
    cout << findAllNonRepeating("dontknowwhattochangetofindallnonrepeatingcharacters") << endl;
}
```

I am not sure what I need to change or add to have this find all of the non repeating characters.

k, f, p, s should be the non repeating characters in this string.

Any hints or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just modify the second loop to find all elements with value=1, isn't that obvious?

Comment: You want to either determine which characters occur once (and return a string instead) or count them, but you're computing the least amount of times an occurring character occurs.

Comment: This feels like a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, simply keep a frequency map. Then, once the string is processed, iterate over the map, returning only those values that occur exactly once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<char> nonRepeating(const std::string& s)
{
    std::map<char, int> frequency;
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
        frequency[s[i]]++;
    }
    std::vector<char> out;
    for(auto it = frequency.begin(); it != frequency.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it->second == 1)
            out.push_back(it->first);
    }
    return out;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::string str = "LoremIpsum";
    for(char c : nonRepeating(str))
    {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joris, I appreciate the help. I am still very beginner in coding! This helped me out a lot.